# DB2: How to concatenate null strings in DB2?

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have to concatenate 2 columns (ex. FIRSTANME and LASTNAME).
I do it this way:

```
FIRSTNAME || ' ' || LASTNAME`.
```

If one of them is null, but the other one is not null, I get null as concatenation result.
And I want following behavior

```
FIRSTNAME = null and LASTNAME = "Smith" ==> 
  FIRSTANME || ' ' || LASTNAME == ' Smith'.
```

How to solve this in DB2?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `coalesce`

```
...
CONCAT( COALESCE(firstname,'') , COALESCE(lastname,'') )
```

Or using the `||` concat operator

```
...
COALESCE(firstname,'') || COALESCE(lastname,'')
```

Note that IBM recomments using the keyword `concat` and not the `||` operator.

Concat: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref%2Ffconc.htm
Coalesce: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref%2Ffcoal.htm